# How to identify Left and Right Click together with 0xFF

Tags: python, opencv

I have a image capturing program that will capture any frame from webcam when certain key on keyboard are pressed. Currently I want to create an alternatives besides using keyboard which is to use mouseclick but I need both to be working. Here is the code :

```
    while True:
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = video_capture.read()

        pressedKey = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

        #take picture
        if pressedKey == ord('c'):
            cv2.imwrite('./results/'+str(subject)+'_'+str(position)+'_'+rgba[counter]+'.png',frame)
            counter= counter + 1
            details=str(subject)+','+str(position)+','+str(counter)+'\n'
            with open('./details.txt', 'a') as f:
                f.write(details)
            print("Image taken succesfully")
        #quit
        elif pressedKey== ord('q'):
            print("Closing application")
            break
        cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
```

I want to take a picture by pressing either "c" or using LMouseClick and quit by pressing "q" or using RMouseClick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code a bit as I do not have information about subject, position, etc.

Anyways, here is the final version that works as you wanted:

```
import cv2
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

status = 1
# mouse callback function
def mouse_func(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global status
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        cv2.imwrite('save.png',frame)
        details='details'
        with open('./details.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write(details)
        print("Image taken succesfully")

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN:
        status = 0
        print("Closing application")

cv2.namedWindow('Video')
cv2.setMouseCallback('Video',mouse_func)

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    pressedKey = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    #take picture
    if pressedKey == ord('c'):
        cv2.imwrite('save.png',frame)
        details='details'
        with open('./details.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write(details)
        print("Image taken succesfully")
    #quit
    elif pressedKey== ord('q') or status == 0:
        print("Closing application")
        break
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
print("Application Closed")
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

You should create a callback function (`mouse_func`), then you should check right and left click using `EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN` and `EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN`.

Note that, there is a global variable `status` which is set to `0` if any right-click occurs. Then, in the main loop, we check if pressed key is `q` OR if `status` is set to `0`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is exactly what I wanted. The subject, position, etc. is not important since it just counter so I didn't put inside the code